# Generating random Numbers , but it must be Generated with Unique numbers without replications

Tags: java, random

```
int[] drawNumbers = new int[10];//Array With 10 Random Numbers USED for DRAWN NUMBERS
String x = "Drawn Numbers: ";
List<Ticket> ticketWon ;

do{
    //GENERATING 10 Random Numbers
    for (int i = 0; i <= drawNumbers.length -1 ; i++) {
           Random r = new Random();
           drawNumbers[i] = r.nextInt(99) + 1;
           x += drawNumbers[i] + " ";
    }
}
```

I'm trying to generate 10 random numbers that must be random generated and Unique. My problem is that with `Random r = new Random()` there are times that replicated numbers are shown. How can i generate 10 random numbers from range 1 to 99 without replications?

Problem is for a Lottery System

I would like to use `Collection.Shuffle` but I'm not that sure how it should be implemented.

Comment: One way would be to put the `Integer`s in a `Set` and when size of set is 10, end the `do while` loop. No `for` loop needed.

Comment: Aaahh, but but how do you know the repetition is not coincidental randomness ? :-).  More seriously, you should really be looking at a cryptographically secure random number generator, not plain Random.

Comment: I.e SecureRandom ... Not Random

Comment: By the way, in terms of your lottery type selection, the typical answer is normally a Fisher-Yates shuffle

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an alternative way to achieve your desired result. We populate a list with values 1 to 99. Then we shuffle the list and grab the first 10 values:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i=1; i<100; i++) {
        list.add(new Integer(i));
    }
    Collections.shuffle(list);
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        System.out.println(list.get(i));
    }
}
```

You won't have to import/directly deal with `Random`, which is a plus. However, as pointed out by @Voicu (in the comments), `shuffle` does indeed utilize random:

```
public static void shuffle(List<?> list) {
    if (r == null) { 
        r = new Random();
    }
    shuffle(list, r);
}
private static Random r;
```

Comment: Although I like this answer (+1), you are still using `Random` behind the scenes (by calling `shuffle` method). Code here: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Collections.java#Collections.shuffle%28java.util.List%29

Comment: @Voicu very good point. I never actually looked at `shuffle` but I'll edit my answer

Comment: +1, though again, this only works well when your range (1-99) is relatively small. `list.subList(0, 10)` would take the first 10 numbers if you want the result in a list.

Answer (score 1):

I'd generate random numbers and save them to a `Set` until I get 10 numbers. Then create a list from it, shuffle it, and then take numbers from it.

```
final int NUMBERS_TO_DRAW = 10;
Random r = new Random();

// Generate NUMBERS_TO_DRAW random numbers 
Set<Integer> randoms = new HashSet<>();
while (randoms.size() < NUMBERS_TO_DRAW) {
    randoms.add(r.nextInt(99) + 1);
}

// Now shuffle them:
List<Integer> shuffledRandom = new ArrayList<>(randoms);
Collections.shuffle(shuffledRandom);
```

EDIT:
As @MarkPeters noted in the comments, using a `LinkedHashSet` would eliminate the need to shuffle:

```
final int NUMBERS_TO_DRAW = 10;
Random r = new Random();

// Generate NUMBERS_TO_DRAW random numbers 
LinkedHashSet<Integer> randoms = new LinkedHashSet<>();
while (randoms.size() < NUMBERS_TO_DRAW) {
    randoms.add(r.nextInt(99) + 1);
}
```

Comment: It would be easier to use a `LinkedHashSet` than have to re-shuffle the list at the end.

Comment: @MarkPeters Agreed - that's much cleaner! I've edited my answer to include this (with proper attribution, of course)

Comment: Looks great; this is the only suggestion that doesn't fall over when you change 99 to `Integer.MAX_INT`.

Answer (score 1):

You can broadly think of this problem as having a deck of cards numbered from 1 to 99, and you want to pick 10 of those cards. The solution would be to, programmatically, create that deck and then randomly select from that deck and remove from the deck.

We can model the deck as a List of Integers and populate that List with entries from 1 to 99 with something like this:

```
List<Integer> deck = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for( int i=1; i<=99; i++ ){
  deck.add( i );
}
```

We then need to pick a random card between the 0th card (lists are numbered starting at 0) and the number of elements in the list:

```
int draw = r.nextRandom( deck.size() );
Integer card = deck.remove( draw );
```

And repeat that 10 times, doing something with the "card" (say, putting it into an array, or another list, or whatever:

```
int drawNumbers = new int[10];
for( int co=0; co<10; co++ ){
  int draw = r.nextRandom( deck.size() );
  Integer card = deck.remove( draw );
  drawNumbers[co] = card;
}
```

Comment: `List` is abstract and cannot be instantiated.

Comment: This is the other great alternative to a set.  It works well for small domains, but not well if you allowed numbers up to 2 billion.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Set<Integer>`.

```
Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();
int[] drawNumbers = new int[10];
Random r = new Random();
for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
{
    drawNumbers[i] = r.nextInt(99) + 1;
    while(set.contains(drawNumbers[i]))
        drawNumbers[i] = r.nextInt(99) + 1;
    set.add(drawNumbers[i]);
}
```

Comment: There are two things you could improve here: 1) a do-while loop would mean you don't have to repeat the line generating the number, and 2) `set.add()` already returns false if the number was already in the list, so you don't need the `contains`.  Just test the call to `add`.

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to use a `list` so you could check if it already contains the number and re-generate if it does.

```
List<Integer> drawNumbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
Random r = new Random();
int newNumber = -1;
do
{
    newNumber = r.nextInt(99) + 1;
} while(drawNumbers.contains(newNumber); //Make sure the number is not already in the list.
```

Then put this in a loop to repeat 10 times.